# Electron.NET: How to add menu?

Tags: .net, .net-core, electron.net

For example: the default menu is
File, Edit, View, Window, Help

I’d like to add my menu item + subitems
File, Edit, View, Tools (Options, Customize), Window, Help

How to do it?
When I do as in example:

```
var menu = new MenuItem[]
{
new MenuItem
{
Label = “Tools”,
Click = async () =>
{
await Electron.Dialog.ShowMessageBoxAsync(“Hello, Tools!”);
}
}
};
Electron.Menu.SetApplicationMenu(menu);
```

It replaces existing menu with my menu Tools, but I need to add it to the existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native Electron has a default development menu.
If you add your own menu, this will be used.
You can not use the development menu and your own menu together..

Comment: Thanks. Ok, even not something like this: get existing menu, insert my item(s), assign back to the app menu?